# Недопустимое значение свойств scss

Tags: css, scss

скопировал linear-gradient с Pixso(Замена Figma) выдает такую ошибку не могу понять. Как исправить и как больше не встречать такую возможную ошибку? Подумал браузер, но в другом тоже самое.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.cta {
padding: 180px 0;

background: linear-gradient(
   180deg,
   $dark 10.42,
   rgba(36, 43, 51, 0) 50.52%,
   $dark 90.1
 ),
 linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(36, 43, 51, 0.9), rgba(36, 43, 51, 0.9)),
 url("./../img/ctabg.jpg"), #c4c4c4;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В коде для градиентов у шагов отсутствуют единицы измерения.

```
180deg,
$dark 10.42, // 1
rgba(36, 43, 51, 0) 50.52%,
$dark 90.1  // 2
```

Если указать единицы измерения, например `%` - то все заработает.

```
180deg,
$dark 10.42%, // 1
rgba(36, 43, 51, 0) 50.52%,
$dark 90.1%  // 2
```

Comment: Благодарю, как то не заметил это. Буду более внимательным.
Спасибо, хорошего вечера.